# Pycharm can't import torch when I run the import command via script, but can import and use in console

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch, torch

As the title states, I am able to successfully import torch via the python console in PyCharm, but when I write a scratch script with just the import command, I get a series of errors. I believe this is likely associated with some sort of issue w/ my selected script path, but I'm not sure which path to choose.

Comment: Sounds to me like an environment issue. Maybe your PyCharm is running in an environment where torch isn't installed. You can use `pip freeze` to list all of the dependencies or `pip freeze | grep 'torch'` to see if torch specifically is installed.

Comment: Please check interpreter and installed packages in `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter`